# Shutdown server using PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell

I know this sounds just wrong, but stay with me for a second.

I have a Raspberry pi which is currently running, I forgot the password, and I want to shut it down so I could remove the SD card and reset the password.

I happen to have an IDE setup with the password, but the IDE has encrypted the password.  As such, I could upload PHP and run it on the ngix webserver I earlier installed.  I'v tried the following, but all it displays is "done".

Recommendations?

PS.  I've asked https://superuser.com/questions/994309/physically-shutdown-raspberry-pi-without-shell-access, and if you know, please either comment or post an answer.

```
<?php
  echo(shell_exec('sudo halt'));
  echo(shell_exec('sudo shutdown'));
  echo(shell_exec('shutdown'));
  echo('done');
?>
```

Comment: `<?php shell_exec("sudo shutdown -h now");?>`

Comment: @AlexAndrei  You mean with `shell` or `shell_exec`, right?  Tried and nothing.

Comment: `shell_exec` is the function name, you can also run <?php \`shutdown -h now\`;?>

Comment: Pulling the plug generally shutsdown devuces without even the need of php!

Comment: @AlexAndrei  Tried it but didn't work.  I didn't know I could do that, thought it would throw an error, but displays nothing (except for the sanity echo I did afterwards).

Comment: @PeeHaa  Yea, but at risk of damaging the device, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your webserver is not running as root you need to use sudo and add your password

try this command

```
'echo your_passwd | /usr/bin/sudo -S shutdown -h -f 0'
```

If you have lost your password, just could pull the plug and change the password in /etc/shadow

Comment: Lost the password. as described by original post.

Comment: shutdown requires root - just pull the plug.